# Download multiple files from Ftp issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows

I want to download some files from my ftp server. The problem is, that only the last one has data, others 0 sized or it crashes when close `QFile` as a pointer.

**My code:**

```
QFtp *ftp = new QFtp(this);
ftp->connectToHost(FTP_HOST, FTP_PORT);
ftp->login(FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
QFile *reportFile = nullptr;

connect(ftp, &QFtp::listInfo, [this](const QUrlInfo &ftpUrlInfo) {
        if (ftpUrlInfo.isFile()) {
            reportFile = new QFile("some local path" + ftpUrlInfo.name());
            reportFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            ftp->get("some ftp path" + ftpUrlInfo.name(), reportFile, QFtp::Binary);
        }
    });
connect(ftp, &QFtp::done, [this]() {
        qDebug() << "DONE!";
        ftp->close();
        ftp->deleteLater();
    });
connect(ftp, &QFtp::commandFinished, [this]() {
        qDebug() << "COMMAND FINISHED!";

            if (reportFile != nullptr) {
                reportFile.close();
                reportFile->deleteLater();
            }
    });

ftp->list("ftp path to dir");
```

So, it should download the file, close it and `deleteLater` for all files in the ftp directory. Any ideas how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need reportFile on the heap? You can simply use  `ftp->get("some ftp path" + ftpUrlInfo.name(), 0, QFtp::Binary);` and connect to `readyRead()`

Comment: You are attempting to download the files while you are still retrieving the directory listing. FTP can't multiplex like that. Have your `listInfo` handler save the file info to a local list, then after the `list` command is done, you can loop through the local list to download each file

Comment: @user3606329

I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

I will try your solution also and reply later. Thanks.

Comment: @user3606329

I have tried it, but the same issue still exists. I think I should use some sort of queue and download file one by one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

The same issue still exists when I loop through the files names. Or you suggest to create/hold `QList<QFile*>` list of files?

Comment: Yes, you have to do everything one thing at a time. FTP is a synchronous command/response protocol, you can't send a new command until a previous command has been replied to. I don't know how Qt works, but if your code runs asynchronously then yes, you need a queuing system of some kind to send the next command when a previous command finishes. And yes, I was implying something like `QList<QFile*>`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

QFtp has signal when ftp command finished - `commandFinished`, and `done` signal when all ftp commands finished, but my problem is with wrong file management. I will try QList<QFile*> and queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed it!

**My code:**

```
QQueue<QFile*> reportQueue; //initialize the queue

connect(ftp, &QFtp::listInfo, [this](const QUrlInfo &ftpUrlInfo) {
        if (ftpUrlInfo.isFile()) {
            reportQueue.append(new QFile("local path" + "\\" + ftpUrlInfo.name()));
        }
    });
    connect(ftp, &QFtp::done, [this]() {
        emit reportsDataFinished();
    });
    connect(ftp, &QFtp::commandFinished, [this]() {
        if (ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::List) {
            proceedDownload();
        } else if (ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Get) {
            reportFile->close();
            reportFile->deleteLater();
            proceedDownload();
        }
    });

    if (ftp->error() == QFtp::NotConnected) {
        emit ftpReportError(ftp->error());
    } else {
        ftp->list("ftp path to the dir");
    }

void Test::proceedDownload()
{
    if (!reportQueue.isEmpty()) {
        reportFile = reportQueue.dequeue();
        reportFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        QFileInfo ftpFileInfo(reportFile->fileName());
        ftp->get("ftp path to file" + "/" + ftpFileInfo.fileName(), reportFile, QFtp::Binary);
    }
}
```

I added the files to the `QQueue`, when ftp `list` command has been finished, I use function `proceedDownload()`. In the function, I `dequeue()` the queue to the `reportFile` and proceed with ftp `get()` function. When `get` ftp command finishes, I `close` and `delete` the file from memory, and again call the `proceedDownload()`. So the the whole process goes again until the queue is empty. I use `emit reportsDataFinished();` signal in the connection to the slot `closeFtp()` where ftp closes and `deleteLater()` frees the resources. All files downloads well. Thank you.